# Where can I find publicly available data on aggregate enrollment in health insurance *before* Medicare?

Tags: medical, historical

I'm looking for data on the number/share of people who had private health insurance by age *and region* (county, for example) **before** the introduction of Medicare in the United States? As in, before 1965?

Comment: Much more aggregate data is available here http://www.nber.org/papers/w11609

Comment: @dzeltzer I'm familiar with that paper, but unfortunately, as you said, the data are much too aggregated for my purposes.